# setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod() not taking effect

Tags: android, beacon, eddystone

I am trying to detect `beacon` once every 30 sec in the background and when the app is in the foreground it should constantly detect the beacon without any interval. For that this is the code that I have written,

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mBeaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    Identifier myBeaconNamespaceId = Identifier.parse("0xe2bfcc3cc2370789caef");
    Region region = new Region("my-beacon-region", myBeaconNamespaceId, null, null);

    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(25000l);
    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000l);
    mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(60000l);
    mBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0l);

    try {
        mBeaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

}
```

Even though I have set the specific scan period, it still detects the beacons at the default time interval. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that setting the foreground scan interval to:

```
mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(60000l);
```

Will not deliver results constantly.  It will scan for 60 seconds, then deliver results onlycat the end of that interval.

Also, the call to `updateScanInterval` will always throw an exception because the service is not yet bound.  That should be OK, because it the code pre-inits the new scan intervals so when service binding happens later the scan intervals will take effect.

Comment: Thanks, now i know that i have to set foreground scan period around 2000 ms. But how can I make my app look for beacons every 30 sec in the background, it still looks for beacons every ~5 min in the background...what changes should I make in my existing code?

Comment: mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000l); /* 30 secs */

Comment: That too does not work. But there's one thing that I have noticed here. I have  a alarm manager in my app and whenever the alarm fires the beacon gets detected. So now I am going to make a alarm that will be fired every 30 secs. This might not be the ideal solution...but it works nevertheless :)